# How to convert str into int through map function?

Tags: python

```
p1  = int(input("Enter the probablity of rain"))
pab = input("Enter the probablity of Alice taking bus")
pmb = input("Enter the probablity of mark taking bus")

Final_Outcome_in_int = map(int,pab)

print(type(p1))
print(type(pab))
print(type(pmb))
```

In this p1 is showing int but for pab its still showing str although I used map function.

Comment: `map` creates a new iterable, which you put in `Final_Outcome_in_int`. You even named it correctly. No reason to expect `pab` to change type.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing:

```
Final_Outcome_in_int = map(int,pab)
```

You're doing to every character, so you want only `pab`

```
Final_Outcome_in_int = int(pab)
```

Both `pab` and `pmb`:

```
Final_Outcome_in_int = map(int, [pab,pmb])
```

Comment: Ive done this method on pycharm but its still showing str not int

Comment: @AnirudhRawat Edited mine

Answer (score 0):

`map` applies the function to a *sequence* of arguments, and produces a *new* sequence. You main syntax is right, but you are using one. You could do something like

```
both_probabilities = map(int, [pab, pmb])
```

If you have a single value, it's just `prob = int(pab)`.

Comment: Ive done this method on pycharm but its still showing str not int

Comment: @AnirudhRawat: pycharm might be wrong. try `print(type(prob))`